Story about a trio of characters travelling through a swamp and fighting spider-like creatures
I read this when I was a child in school. Here are the details that I remember:
It takes place in the future or on another planet. I thought there were 3 characters. They were traveling from one place to another. Something makes me think they were in a swamp at one point fighting creatures (maybe spider like creatures). Not sure if they were mutants or one of them was. Also not sure if they were marines or soldiers. But I thought during this battle they were having in the swamp against these creatures, one of them sacrificed themselves using some sort of grenade or a similar device.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  We don't know when you were a child, so approximately what year would this have been?  Was this a novel, or just a shorter story?

Perhaps Bob Shaw's Night Walk? Two blind characters traverse a swamp after escaping from an extraterrestrial prison. One steps into the mouth of a spider-like pit-trap creature. The men kill the spider, but then the injured man is killed by a heat-seeking rocket fired from the prison's anti-escape system.

That may be the book! I bought it and will check it out. I’ll keep you posted. Thanks for the help!

Had you said fantasy instead of sci-fi, I would have suggested Memory, Sorrow, and Thorn.  Can't remember which book in the series, but it also involves three characters traveling in a swamp attacked by spider like creatures.  No one blows up though.
